# How to call a web service function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, webservice-client

I am trying to consume a SAP web service using Python. I am able to get the response, but I when calling the method in it I get an error in response.
How do I call a web service method using Python?

**Python code:**

```py
from suds.client import Client
import json
wsdl_url = "<URL>"
client = Client(url = wsdl_url, username = "<username>", password = "<password>")
print(client)
x = client.service[0].Methods[1]
print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
Suds ( https://github.com/cackharot/suds-py3 )  version: 1.3.3.0 IN  build: 20170311

Service ( ziot_service1 ) tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" Prefixes (1)
      ns0 = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"    Ports (2):
      (ziot_service1)
         Methods (1):
            ZIOT_SERVICE1()
         Types (3):
            char10
            char4
            date10
      (ziot_service1_soap12)
         Methods (1):
            ZIOT_SERVICE1()
         Types (3):
            char10
            char4
            date10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "webservice0.py", line 6, in <module>
    x = client.service[0].Methods[1]   File "C:\Users\Sid-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 511, in __getattr__
    return self[name]   File "C:\Users\Sid-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 524, in __getitem__
    raise MethodNotFound(qn) suds.MethodNotFound: Method not found: 'ziot_service1.ziot_service1.Methods'
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Give definition of your web-service (wsdl), it seems you misspelled method name or it is non-existant

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use the method name. You can try this:

```
x = client.service[0].ZIOT_SERVICE1()
```

I would check this also, just in case:

```
x = client.service[1].ZIOT_SERVICE1()
```

Another way to call the WS method is to retrieve it by its name:

```
ziot_method = getattr(client.service[0],'ZIOT_SERVICE1')
x = ziot_method()
```